# Adding floating point numbers together using guard bits + rounding

Tags: computer-science

Am I doing this right? My textbook does not go into detail about what to do...

> Calculate (3.984375 * 10^(-1) + 3.4375 * 10^(-1) + 1.771 * 10^3 by hand, assuming each of the values are stored in the 16-bit half precision format described in Exercise 3.27 (and also described in the text). Assume 1 guard, 1 round bit, and 1 sticky bit, and round to the nearest even. Show all the steps, and write your answer in both the 16-bit floating point format and in decimal.

So first off, I have to convert the values to binary:

How do I convert 3.984375 * 10^(-1) to binary scientific notation first off?

Comment: "binary scientific notation" doesn't mean anything other than convert the numbers to the 16 bit half precision specified in exercise 3.27. There are numerous formats possible in 16 bits so the question is not answerable here w/o more detail.

Comment: You might start by noting that 3.984375 is exactly 255/64 Think about it